# Interspersing of integers by rationals

Tags: analysis, self-learning

I'm wondering if the next argument is sound or maybe need some adjustments;

**Proposition** (Interspersing of integers by rationals): Let $x\in \mathbb{Q}$. Then there exists an integer such that $n\le x< n+1$. In fact this integer is unique. In particular, there exists a natural number $N$ such that $N>x$ (i.e. there is no such thing as a rational number which is larger than all the natural numbers).

Proof: By the trichotomy property of the rational numbers, either $x$ is positive, negative or zero.

If $x=0$, it's trivial since $\,0 \le x<1$.

Now if $x$ is positive number, by definition $x= \frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q\in \mathbb{N}- \left\{0 \right\}$. Then using the Euclidean algorithm we have that:

$$p = mq+r, \text{  where   } \:\: 0 \le r < q $$

We shall show that the natural number $m$ has the desired property $\,m \le x < m+1$. It is sufficient to show that $\,\,0 \le x-m<1$.

$x -m= \frac{p}{q}-m =\frac{mq+r}{q}-{m} = \frac{r}{q}$. Since by the Euclidean algorithm we know that $\,0 \le r < q$  then $\,0 \le \frac{r}{q} <1$ as desired.

Now suppose there is a $n \not= m $ such that $p = nq+r$. So, $\,mq+r = nq+r$ and we conclude that $m=n$ which show the uniqueness of $m$.

If $x$ is a negative rational number, we have that $x = \frac{-a\,}{\,\,\,b\,}$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{N}- \left\{0\right\}$, so $-x = \frac{a}{b}$ and we may  use the same argument that in the positive case.

To conclude we need to show that the integer is unique and is follows of the above argument.

I feel that the argument is a bit flawed, I would appreciate any suggestion. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your argument is sound. It makes assumptions about the uniqueness of the remainder, which may or may not be acceptable. I would avoid the Euclidean algorithm, and go back to basics. If $x$ is positive, then $x=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p$ and $q$ are wlg positive. Then $p+1\gt x$. Let $m$ be the smallest non-negative integer such that $x\lt m$. Then $n=m-1$ does the job.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thanks very helpful. Indeed almost all the proof avoid the Euclidean algorithm but in the notes of Terry Tao he encourages to use it. To be honest I don't feel completely comfortable with my proof because I assume as you said the uniqueness of the remainder.

Comment: You can prove uniqueness by observing that if $n\lt n'$ and $n\le x\lt n+1$ then $x\lt n'$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: First of all Thanks again :). So, maybe I can argue something like this: Suppose for the sake of the contradiction that there is other natural number $n'$ such that $n' \not=n$ and have the same property(i.e.,  $n'\le x< n'+1$). Then, without lose of generality we may assume that $n<n'$ so $n+1\le n'$. Thus, we have  $x<n+1\le n'$ it follows that $x<n'$ which contradicts our assumption that $n' \le x$. Therefore $n$ is unique.

Comment: Yes, that is fine. After a while, this kind of detail is unnecessary, but it is good to do it a few times, so that oone knows it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that $m$ is a natural number, then we should have $p\ge q$. If $p<q$, and both positive, then anyway $0\le p/q<1$. Otherwise the proof should work like what you did. It is enough to consider the case that $x$ is positive, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, so using the Euclidean algorithm for the sake of the completeness I need to add the case $p<q$ and the argument as far as it goes is ok, right?  :)

Answer (score 2):

Much depends on your axioms and definitions, but I think it's probably simpler to skip the Euclidean algorithm and skip straight down to the well-ordering principle. Prove first that for any rational $q$ there is an integer $n$ such that $q \le n$.

Comment: Thanks, let me try this other approach but as in the notes of Terry Tao, he suggests the Euclidean algorithm that was the reason.